# Morphisms between schemes such that every point in the codomain has at most $n$ preimages.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Consider a **finite** morphism $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ between two integral and Noetherian schemes. If $\operatorname {deg}(f)=[K(X):K(Y)]=n$,  is it true that for every $y\in Y$ then $|f^{-1}(y)|\le n$? (with the notation $|\cdot|$ I mean the cardinality). I know that $|f^{-1}(y)|<\infty$ but what about its upper bound? If the statement is false as stated here, under which other hypothesis we have that $|f^{-1}(y)|\le n$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say "I know that $|f^{-1}(y)|<\infty$", but that is false. Think about a birational map that contracts a curve: what is the degree of the field extension? Even if $f$ is finite the bound you want doesn't work: $f$ could be the normalisation of a nodal curve.

Comment: Finite morphism doesn't imply finite fibers? (finite morphisms are quasi-finite)

Comment: But you did not say that your morphism is finite, just that it induces a finite extension of function fields. My point is exactly that this is weaker. (Search for "generically finite".) Also, the second example is finite.

Comment: yeah you're right I forgot to write that $f$ is finite. Is a typo.

Comment: I've edited. Many thanks!

Comment: On the other hand *if $Y$ is normal*, this should be true. See Shafarevich Volume 1, II.6.3 Theorem 3 for a proof in the case of varieties.

Comment: What is unsatisfactory about Asal Beag Dubh's comment?

Answer (score 3):

This is Asal Beag Dubh's answer.

Consider the finite ring map $k[x, y]/(y^2 - xy - x^3) \to k[t]$ with $x \mapsto t(t - 1)$ and $y \mapsto t^2(t - 1)$. Take Spec of this. Then $n = 1$ but the fibre over $(0, 0)$ has two points.

If $Y$ is normal, then the result does hold, but it isn't that easy to prove. One way to do it is to reduce to the case where the extension of function fields is Galois (say with group $G$; this reduction already takes a bit of work in case of inseparability) and then to show that the fibres of $X \to Y$ are acted on transitively by $G$ (in case $X$ is normal) as in one of the proofs of going down for finite over normal.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up, @answer_bot. (I am not sure how much sense it makes to thank a bot, but never mind.)