# When is "number of points in the fiber" semicontinuous?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a finite morphism of schemes. For $y \in Y$ let $n(y)$ be the cardinality of the set-theoretic fiber $f^-1(y)$. This is finite since $f$ is finite.

I think that the function $n$ is not upper semicontinuous, is this correct? (I think in the comments of [Cardinality of the Fiber of a Finite Morphism Vs. Degree (via Vakil)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480936/cardinality-of-the-fiber-of-a-finite-morphism-vs-degree-via-vakil) there is a counter-example but I'm not 100% sure).

My question is: are there any nice conditions implying that $n$ is semicontinuous?

Assuming $Y$ is integral with generic point $\xi$ I guess in general the set $\lbrace y \in Y \mid n(y) = n(\xi) \rbrace$ is not open in $X$, is it? Is it constructible in general? Perhaps normality of $Y$ is an important ingredient (see [Morphisms between schemes such that every point in the codomain has at most $n$ preimages.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719962/morphisms-between-schemes-such-that-every-point-in-the-codomain-has-at-most-n))?

Comment: If you don't take `geometric' points, there will be issues. For example, $f$ could be a covering map of smooth irreducible varieties, so over the generic point, there is only one point, but at all geometric points, there are $\deg f$ number of points.